# Creating bash function with parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to prompt affirmation question when i entered `rm -rf` to terminal, if answered it "yes", the operation will be performed. I found something like this for directly `rm` command:

```
rm() {
    read -p "Type password? " pass
    if [ "$pass" = "1234" ]; then
         command rm "$@"
    else
         #Termination and echo a message wrong pass. 
    fi
}
```

for adding to .bashrc. and converted it to:

```
rm(){
    if [ $1 -eq "-" ] && [ $2 -eq "r" ] && [ $2 -eq "r" ]; then
        read -p "Do you really want to delete?" ans
    if [ ans -eq "yes" ]; then
        rm -rf $@;
    else
    fi
    
    else
    fi
}
```

But i know it will not work. So how can i detect `rm -rf` commands and prompt my custom affirmation question?

Edit: I have this right now but still no luck:

```
rm(){
    if [ $1 = "-rf" ]; then
        read -p "Do you really want to delete?" ans;
        
    if [ $ans = "yes" ]; then
        rm -rf "$@";
    fi

    fi
}
```

Comment: If you get the habit to always use `rm -rfI` instead of `rm -rf`, I think you will be asked back even with the standard `rm`; no need to write a wrapper function which tries to analyze the parameters. You can do a `alias rmrf=rm -rfI` to save typing.

Comment: Should this also happen if you call `rm` with `-r -f` or `-fr` or `-f -r` or `-rif`, or other combinations of args that include `r` and `f` or **only** when you do `rm -rf`?

Comment: This type of wrapper gets you into the bad habit of assuming that `rm -rf` will *always* ask you if you are sure. If you want such a wrapper, don't name it `rm`; call it `rmc`(`c` for "confirm"), and if one day you find yourself on a machine without your safety net, you are more likely to get a "command not found" error than deleting a bunch of files without confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind `rm -fr`, `rm -r -f`, etc. not being caught, this'll work fine:

```
rm()
  if [[ $1 = -rf ]]; then
    read -p 'Are you sure? ' reply
    if [[ $reply = yes ]]; then
      command rm "$@"
    fi
  fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. It isn't particularly trivial to cover all cases (`-rf`, `-fr`, `-r -f`, `--recursive --force`, `-R --force`; or other combinations, e.g. `-vrvfv` – [`getopts`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html) might help).

Here's a function to get your started.

```
rm() {
  local use_force=0
  local is_recursive=0

  for arg; do
    case "$arg" in
      --force) use_force=1 ;;
      --recursive) is_recursive=1 ;;
      # skip remaining long options:
      --*) continue ;;
      # handle short options:
      -*)
        while getopts :frFR flag "$@"; do
          case "$flag" in
            [fF]) use_force=1 ;;
            [rR]) is_recursive=1 ;;
          esac
        done
        ;;
    esac
  done

  if [ "$use_force" = 1 ] && [ "$is_recursive" = 1 ]; then
    read -p 'Do you really want to delete?' answer
    case "$answer" in
      [yY]*) command rm "$@" ;;
      *) echo 'Skipping delete ...' ;;
    esac
  else
    # only -f/--force, only -R/-r/--recursive, or neither
    command rm "$@"
  fi
}
```

You didn't really specify how you would want to handle `rm -r dir` or `rm -f file` (so only recursive or only force, but not in combination). I assumed that you will not get a confirmation question in that case.

Comment: Answer has been updated to make use of the `getopts` utility for more robust parsing of the options.